# eliminar botones ok/reintentardel intent de la camara

Tags: android

Cuando ejecuto el intent para hacer la foto, se abre la camara. Al realizar la foto, esta me pide confirmacion con un ok y un  reintentar , lo raro es que solo me lo pide en un adnroid 6.0.1(Samsung S6), en un andorid 4.3(sony xperia v) no, hace la foto,la guarda y acaba.

Pues bien, me gustaria justamente lo que sucede en el xperia, que hiciera la foto y terminara, no que necesitara confirmar que la foto ha salido bien.

Os adjunto el codigo con que llamo a la camara:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
File tarjeta=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
String filePath = tarjeta.getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+"Reuniones"+File.separator+String.valueOf(id2) +File.separator+"fotos"+File.separator+ generarNombreFoto();

Uri output = Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath));
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, output);
startActivityForResult(intent, 5);
```

Comment: Una pregunta Sergio, siempre te pide "reintentar"?

Comment: Hola Elena!, si, con el Samsung siempre me pide que acepte con OK o reintente con REINTENTAR. Como decia, en el Sony no,

Comment: Eso es por que ese intent abre la aplicación de la cámara del dispositivo y esta puede variar en todos los dispositivos, si necesitas una funcionalidad homogénea en todos los dispositivos que ejecuten tu aplicación tienes que crear tu propia clase para la cámara.

Comment: la verdad que no sabria ni por donde empezar, aun asi muchas gracias  Bourne!

Comment: acabo de comprobar que cambiando el parametro del intent de MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE a MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA se soluciona el problema y permite hacer todas las fotos que quieras seguido. El problema aparece cuando no almacena las fotos en la carpeta que le asigno, al contrario que pasaba con la otra forma que si lo hacia....algun consejo?

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que el intent lo que hace es abrir la aplicación por defecto que tiene seleccionada el usuario para "sacar fotos" , por lo tanto todo lo que pasa desde que lanzas el intent queda fuera de tu control hasta que la otra app devuelve el resultado. Es por eso que tienes experiencias distintas en distintos dispositivos ya que puede haber sido modificada la aplicación por defecto o el usuario puede haber instalado otra aplicación que saque fotos.

La unica forma de controlar la experiencia sería implementar tu mismo la logica para sacar la foto, lo cual no es terriblemente complejo pero deberías considerar si el esfuerzo vale la pena para tu proyecto.